# VS Code debugger not breaking on uncaught Error in Express route handler

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, error-handling

If an error throws in an Express route handler, it will only break with the debugger if Caught Exceptions is checked. I don't want to check this option because I want to ignore errors I've explicitly caught.

How can I get errors in my routes to trigger a debugger break without turning on Caught Exceptions?

I've also tried catching exceptions in Express middleware and then adding a breakpoint there, which works with Caught Exceptions off, but I lose the original stack trace.

Comment: Express is probably catching the error for you, so it's no longer uncaught.

Comment: @CherryDT right that's what I suspect is happening, but I don't know how to work around that with Express and VS Code

Comment: Can you add some example code please?